# What is completer method supposed to return in the Node.js readline module if there's nothing to match?

Tags: node.js, readline

It's not mentioned in the docs
http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: its mentioned in the docs, pay more attention at the example, it must return an Array.

Comment: Yes an array, or there would be an exception. But what's the elements of them if there's nothing to complete?

Comment: its an optional function parameter. In common call, `line` (user input) is passed as first parameter, what it will return is clearly up to you. The elements must look like, `[[str1,str2],UserInput]`

Comment: Yes. But how about that when there's no candicates? In my projects, the `line` is `xxxx` and I don't want the `completer` do anything on `<tab>`, currently it returns `[[], null]`, https://github.com/Cirru/cirru-shell/blob/master/coffee/shell.coffee#L20 But is there a suggested solution for that.

Comment: well if there are no candidates, you could show all available commands or the first 10 or 20 until the user starts typing again.

Comment: No. Suppose current line is `print valv`. Look at `valv`, which should be part of `value`. It's a typo. I don't want any candicates to be printed.

Answer (score 3):

By reading such code in `readline` module, just passing `[]` is fine:

```
var completions = rv[0],
    completeOn = rv[1];  // the text that was completed
if (completions && completions.length) {
  // Apply/show completions.
  if (completions.length === 1) {
    self._insertString(completions[0].slice(completeOn.length));
  } else {
    self.output.write('\r\n');
```

when `completions` is `undefined`, nothing would follow.